# Message '! Missing \endcsname inserted.' calling \msg_error:nn

Tags: expl3, latex3

I get the message

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \delimiter 
l.58 ...ore than two arguments for {\backslash}Id}

?
```

For this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{}}
  {
     \Id:n {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \int_case:nnF
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}
        {
         \operatorname{Id}
        }
        {1}
        {
         \operatorname{Id} \sb {#1}
        }
        {2}
        {
         \operatorname{Id}
           \sp {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
           \sb {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {
          \msg_error:nn {shmuel} {More than two arguments for {\backslash}Id}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn {shmuel} {short} {##1}
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {##1} {##2}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test $\Id$, $\Id[A]$ and $\Id[{A,B}]$ inline.
\begin{equation}
  \text{Test} \ \Id, \\
   \Id[A], \\
   \Id[{A,B}]
\end{equation}

%Test $\Id[{too},{many},{parms}]$

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_error:nn {shmuel} {More than two arguments for {\backslash}Id}

\end{document}
```

I updated the code to reflect comments and modified it to support two similar commands, \Id and \ID, differing only in the case of the text they generate. However, I have been unable to get a backslash in the message text without also getting extraneous text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{}}
  {
     \Id:nn {Id} {#1}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \ID {O{}}
  {
     \Id:nn {ID} {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:nn #1 #2
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \int_case:nnF
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}q
        {
         \operatorname{#1}
        }
        {1}
        {
         \operatorname{#1} \sb {#2}
        }
        {2}
        {
         \operatorname{#1}
           \sp {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
           \sb {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {
         \msg_error:nnnn {shmuel} {toomany} {two} {#1: [#2]}
      }
  }

\msg_new:nnn {shmuel} {short} {#1}
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {#1} {#2}
\msg_new:nnnn
  {shmuel}
  {toomany}
  {More \ than \ #1  \ items \ for \ \string\\#2}
  %                                  {\textbackslash}#2?

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test \ $\Id$, \  $\Id[A]$ \  and \  $\Id[{A,B}]$ \ inline.
\begin{equation}
  \text{Test} \ \Id, \\
   \Id[A], \\
   \Id[{A,B}]
\end{equation}

Test $\Id[{too},{many},{parms}]$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered in the answer to the previous question, although the error highlighte in that question was in a different part of the code. You do not want `\backslash` here which is causing the error, this is a version using `#1` in the error message to show the over-long list. note that `\msg_error` should just refer to the message by module and name, not the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{}}
  {
     \Id:n {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \int_case:nnTF
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}
        {
          \mathop{\mathrm{Id}}
        }
        {1}
        {
          \mathop{\mathrm{Id}}\sb{#1}
        }
        {2}
        {
          \mathop{\mathrm{Id}}
            \sp{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
            \sb{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {}
      {
          \msg_error:nnn {shmuel}{long} {#1}
      }
  }

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {more\ than\ two\ arguments\ for\ \string\Id:\ #1} {help}
\ExplSyntaxOff

Test $\Id$, $\Id[A]$ and $\Id[A,B]$ $\Id[{too},{many},{parms}] $ inline.
\begin{equation}
  Test \Id, \\
   \Id[A], \\
   \Id[A,B]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is it an error to use \backspace? Why does \msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {toomany} {More \ than \ #1  \ items \ for \ #2} followed by  \msg_error:nnnn {shmuel} {toomany} {two} {\string\\#1: \[#2\]} give ! Package shmuel Error: More than two items for \string
(shmuel)                \\Id:\[{too},{many},{parms}\] instead of ! Package shmuel Error: More than two items for (shmuel)                \Id:\[{too},{many},{parms}\]? Should I edit my question to show the complete code?

Comment: @shmuel `\backslash` is a math command to make a \ operator it doesn't make a literal \ in a message the code in this answer produces a message of `! Package shmuel Error: more than two arguments for \Id:{too},{many},{parms}` don't change it back to the wrong version. the text should be in the `\msg_new` as I show not the `\msg_error`

Comment: The fixed text is in the \msg_new. What I have is essentially the same error message for two outer (interface) macros, \Id and \ID, using a common expl3 subroutine. Should I use {textbackslash}#1, and is that valid in Math mode?

Comment: @shmuel I guess you want `\msg_error:nnnn {shmuel} {toomany} {two} {#1: [#2]} `

Comment: Does that men that there's no way to get a backslash in the error message?

Comment: @shmuel why do you say that?, both the error message in this answer and the one you say you got have backslashes,

Comment: The one that I got didn't just have a backslash, it had the extraneous word "string". I removed it from \msg_error:nnnn and put \string\\#2 in \msg_new:nnnn (I got \string\\ from TeX By Topic) and that almost worked, but I got \\ instead of \.

Comment: @shmuel did you try what I suggested in the comment above?

Comment: That doesn't give me a backslah in the message.

Comment: @shmuel it will if #1 is a command name like `\foo` but as you haven't shown what you did I can't really guess. perhaps you are looking for `\c_backslash_str` ?

Comment: #1 is not a command name; it is either Id or ID. I asked whether to edit the question to include that code and got no answer. I'll be happy to edit it in, or to answer my own question and include it, if you believe that to be appropriate.

Comment: @shmuel whatever. Twice now you've asked a question and I've answered it as asked, then you've asked a different question in comments, if you can edit the question without completely invalidating this answer feel free, I may update the answer to match.

Comment: Would {\c_backslash_str}#2 work? I'm currently at a hotel whose customer-facing computers won't let me use my portable MiKTeX, so I can't test it. I was, however, able to read the file and paste it into my question.

Comment: @shmuel if I understand what you want then I assume `\c_backslash_str #2` (no braces) would do what you want.

Comment: \c_backslash_str #2 (no braces) abut \ with the value of #2 (what I want), or would there be an intervening space.?

Comment: I'm back home and was able to verify that \c_backslash_str #2 (without the braces} does abut the \ to the text. Thanks.